# AngularJS form input gets undefined

Tags: angularjs, forms

I use a lot of forms in my app, but for some reason, one of them (the simplest one, actually) doesn't work properly. When I submit it, the value of the input which is given by my console.log is "undefined".

I'm pretty sure it's a very simple mistake, but I can't see it.

I tried to use "form = 'forgottenForm' " in my inputs, I also tried ng-model but it's useless since I'm not displaying the value of "email", I just want to submit it and then perform some database operations.

**HTML**

```
<form name="forgottenForm" id='forgottenForm' novalidate="" ng-controller="forgottenCtrl">
    <label class="forgotten-item item item-input">
        <input type="text" name="forgottenEmail" required>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="button" ng-click="submitForgotten(forgottenEmail)">Valider</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('ionicApp').controller("forgottenCtrl", function($scope, $http, $ionicPopup, $cookies, $rootScope, $window, $q){
    $scope.submitForgotten = function(forgottenEmail){
        console.log(forgottenEmail);
    }
})
```

Comment: change to `ng-model="forgottenEmail"` (you can also have `ng-submit` on the form itself instead of `ng-click` on your button)

Comment: Yeah that was it, I don't know why I figured that the parameter read was "name" and not "ng-model". Thank you for that.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, you should change that comment to an answer :)

Comment: @SteveDanner ye, but nah. points < (quick) help

Comment: While I like the spirit and agree with you to a degree, a true, good answer (such as yours) marked as THE answer by the OP may help many others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to change to `ng-model="forgottenEmail"`.

It is also possible to have `ng-submit` on the form itself instead of `ng-click` on the button.

Thanks to [Aleksey Solovey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495123/aleksey-solovey) for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work,

1. You have to declare a variable in `$scope` like `$scope.email=''`
2. Then you need to set it like this `<input type="text" ng-model='email' name="forgottenEmail" required>`

Actually you don't need to pass the variable submit function

```js
angular.module('ionicApp').controller("forgottenCtrl", function($scope, $http, $ionicPopup, $cookies, $rootScope, $window, $q) {
  $scope.email = '';
  $scope.submitForgotten = function() {
    console.log($scope.email);
  }
})
```

```html
<form name="forgottenForm" id='forgottenForm' novalidate="" ng-controller="forgottenCtrl">
  <label class="forgotten-item item item-input">
     <input type="text" ng-model='email' name="forgottenEmail" required>
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="button" ng-click="submitForgotten()">Valider</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I give you a "thumb up" because I know this works, but I don't mark the answer as accepted, because I was waiting for something which doesn't change the structure of the form (someone corrected me in the comments). But thank you for your answer. :)